# meaning of the word "dressing" in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning

Can you please tell me what exactly does *"dressing"* mean in this paragraph?

(it's from a book about management and leadership):

> "the second way to see yourself as a leader is to stake indirectly
>   claims of leadership, such as sitting at the head of the table for a
>   meeting, mentioning your relationship with recognized leaders, or
>   dressing the part."

is it something like acting out the part or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

[**To dress the part**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dress-look-act-the-part) means:

to have an appearance or wear clothing that is usual or expected for a particular situation, activity, or job/ to look suitable or behave in a suitable way for a particular situation.

Example:

If you want to be taken seriously in business, you have to **dress the part**.

Comment: so you're saying that it's actually talking about having an appearance that makes you look like a leader? would it be appropriate to translate it as "dashtane zaher ya raftare motanaseb ba rahbari" ?

Comment: @navid, yes. Here, you can say ‘مثل رهبرها لباس پوشیدن یا رفتار کردن’.